How to create a histogram in AWS QuickSight without using aggregate functions?
I’m trying to create a histogram in AWS QuickSight to display my IoT data. However, every time I attempt to create a visualization, I only get options with aggregate functions (like average, sum, etc.). This is not what I want, as I need to plot my values over time without any aggregation.
My dataset contains timestamps and corresponding values that I want to plot directly. Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this in QuickSight? Any tips or examples would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
